# How can I calculate the execution time of some method theoretically?

Tags: java, math, theory, timing, execution-time

Suppose I have, "Heap Sort" method which its complexity time is O(nlogn). When I measure the execution time of this method upon 1000000 inputs I got 0.375770669 seconds. How can I calculate the execution time of this method theoretically?

Comment: If you already know it's O(n log n) -- or Θ(n log n) to be more precise -- then what do you want to calculate theoretically? Do you want to know how to arrive at the number "0.375770669 seconds" theoretically?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I want to compare between the measured one and the theoretical one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to calculate this theoretically.  It depends on many factors such as:

- The java edition and major / minor / patch release numbers.
- The various JVM tuning parameters; e.g. how big the heap is.
- Your hardware platform; CPU, memory size, even motherboard and clock speed.
- The load on the machine; i.e. what else it is doing.
- The amount of fluff on the CPU heatsink.  Seriously ... the clock speed may be reduced if the processor chip gets too hot, and the motherboard oscillator clock speed is (a bit) temperature sensitive too.

Even if you knew all of those, the calculation would essentially be a forensic simulation of the Java JIT compiler and hardware execution.  It is far too complicated to contemplate.

The best you can reasonably expect to achieve in terms of a theoretical measure of "speed" is to count abstract operations at the source-code level.  Even drilling down and counting bytecodes executed is probably too difficult to be practical.

> I want to compare between the measured one and the theoretical one.

Basically, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

What you can possibly do is to run your code for various number of inputs such as 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000 etc and record the time spent in sorting. Then plot those records times against # of elements in a X-Y graph and see if you get `O(nlogn)` complexity curve.

Also look at this document for heap sort analysis and demo: http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/heap/heapen.htm

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the O(·) or Θ(·) notation describes the *asymptotic rate of growth*, in the *limit as n approaches infinity*: it describes how slow the algorithm gets as you multiply the input size by 10, say. How closely this corresponds to actual execution time for actual input sizes (which are always infinitely small in comparison with "infinity") depends on how closely the theoretical model used for analysing the algorithm corresponds to the actual machine you have.

Specifically, "heap sort takes Θ(n log n) time" means that there exist constants c<sub>1</sub> and c<sub>2</sub> such that **for sufficiently large n**, if T(n) is the time it takes on an input of size n, then

> c<sub>1</sub>n log n < T(n) < c<sub>2</sub>n log n

A size of n=1000000 may or may not be "sufficiently large n" for the asymptotic behaviour to kick in.

Nevertheless, assuming that it is, and interpreting the statement to mean that the time taken is roughly (cn log n) for some constant c, equating

> c1000000lg(1000000) = 0.375770669 seconds

gives c ≈ 1.88 × 10<sup>-8</sup>. This means that an input of size n=2000000 should take about 0.79 seconds, and n=10000000 should take about 4.38 seconds. You can compare this "theoretical" results with experimental results you get by running the algorithm with an input of that size.

---

A rough rule of thumb for typical computers is that c is somewhere between 10<sup>-7</sup> for slow computers and algorithms, and 10<sup>-9</sup> for reasonably decent ones. Multiply another couple of factors of 10 on either end to be safe. (The idea is that typical analyses give constants c somewhere in, say, 1–200, and typical computers are within an order of magnitude or two in speed. Of course, "typical" is subjective and if you try this with Fibonacci heaps you will probably be disappointed.)

Starting with an *a priori* guess of c about 10<sup>-8</sup> would have given that the running time is about 0.2 seconds.